# Why is Bootstrip grid not working, but buttons are?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, wordpress-theming

Here is the php with bootstrap classes (in the single.php file of my wordpress theme)

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<button class="btn-danger">Hello Bootstrap World</button>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
</div>


<?php 
get_footer(); 
?>
```

and here is an image of the result[image]

Does anyone know why the columns aren't lining up? The bootstrap seems to be enqueued properly in wordpress because the button styling is working.  Here is my enqueue line in wordpress.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' );
}
```

Can anyone give me any other tips on how to get this working properly?

Thank you for any help

Comment: it's a known issue that bootstrap conflicts with the Divi Theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add container. Your CSS may be overridden by other CSS.

Answer (score 1):

you need to wrap the content in a container class.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work.  It just moved all the .col-sm-4 out by about an inch, but they did not line up

Comment: Here is an example of it working [link](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/86361/), so it maybe something else overriding the CSS if it is not working, would you be able to provide a link to a live version

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap follows below grid structure.

The Bootstrap grid system has four classes:

1. xs (for phones - screens less than 768px wide)
2. sm (for tablets - screens equal to or greater than 768px wide)
3. md (for small laptops - screens equal to or greater than 992px wide)
4. lg (for laptops and desktops - screens equal to or greater than
   1200px wide)

So if you want to have 3 columns on desktop put class="col-md-4".

Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp